# Как лучше обозначить производителя?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Я собираюсь за соком, сок какого производителя брать, сок какой фирмы брать, сок какой компании покупать?

Comment: @Сибиряк чтобы дать ответ, пожалуйста, используйте подходящую для этого форму ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Как вам больше нравится. Все приведённые варианты равнозначны.

Answer (score 0):

**Сок какого производителя брать?**

Именно такой вариант используется в передачах о качестве продуктов.

*Сок какой фирмы брать* — это народный разговорный вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы хотите получить действительно полезный и содержательный ответ, то вопрос необходимо задавать так:

> Сок какой торговой марки брать/покупать?

Потому что у одного и того же производителя/компании/фирмы может быть несколько торговых марок, отличающихся составом, качеством, ценовой категорией и т.д.